# How to call didSelectRowAtIndexPath method with UITapGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I've searched for hours on Google and Stackoverflow, tried them but no luck.

I have a UITableView `tblDepartment` and a UISearchBar `studentSearch` above it.

I add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to dismiss the keyboard from `studentSearch` textbox when users tap outside the search box:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];
[self.tblDepartment addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

- (void)hideKeyboard
{
    [studentSearch resignFirstResponder];
}
```

After that, the method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` isn't called anymore when I select row in `tblDepartment`. I know `gestureRecognizer` is the reason.

So, how can I hide the keyboard and still allow user to select row?

I tried this code but it didn't work:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if ([touch.view isDescendantOfView:tblDepartment]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Could you remove the gesture recognizer, and resign first responder from `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` instead?

Comment: Try removing your gesture recognizer after the `resignFirstResponder`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Thank you for your comment. The `tblDepartment` has about 7 rows and the keyboard overlap them when display. I want users to be able to select rows if they don't want to search :) So when they tap outside the searchbox, the keyboard is dismissed and they can select the bottom rows.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Set the gesture recognizer cancelsTouchesInView property to NO, it's YES by default, it prevents touches from reaching the underlying views if the GR recognizes its gesture.

Comment: Great solution. Thank you. `[gestureRecognizer setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];` and it works!

Comment: Thank you really you saved my time :) I wrote like this tap.cancelsTouchesInView=NO;